# How can I perform a case insensitive replace in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I current have the following code:

```js
const pattern = "quick";
const re = new RegExp(pattern, "gi");

const string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy QUICK dog";

const replaced = string.replace(pattern, "<b>" + pattern + "</b>");

console.log(replaced);
```

It produces the following:

```
The <b>quick</b> brown fox jumped over the lazy QUICK dog
```

What I want is:

```
The <b>quick</b> brown fox jumped over the lazy <b>QUICK</b> dog
```

I'm having two issues.

Firstly, why isn't `QUICK` being replaced when I'm using a case insensitive regex?

Secondly, how do I ensure that `QUICK` is replaced with `<b>QUICK</b>` and not `<b>quick</b>`?

Comment: you've created a regexp `re` ... and never use it ... so that's something you should look at - try `const replaced = string.replace(re, "<b>" + pattern + "</b>");
`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass `<b>$&</b>` as the second parameter to `.replace` to insert the matched substring:

```js
const string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy QUICK dog";
console.log(
  string.replace(/quick/gi, '<b>$&</b>')
);
```

Your `QUICK` isn't being replaced in your original code because

```
const replaced = string.replace(pattern,
```

is passing *pattern*, which is a *string*, rather than your constructed regex (whose variable name is `re`). If you had passed `re`, you would see:

```js
const pattern = "quick";
const re = new RegExp(pattern, "gi");
const string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy QUICK dog";
const replaced = string.replace(re, "<b>" + pattern + "</b>");
console.log(replaced);
```

which doesn't preserve the original casing, thus the need for `'<b>$&</b>'`.